# $\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} F_k^\circ$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, baire-category

> Let $\{F_k\}$ be a sequence of closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}}F_k$. Then $\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} F_k^\circ$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. (Here $F_k^\circ$ denotes the interior of the set $F_k$).

Using Baire's Category theorem, I can say that there exist at leat one $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $F_k^\circ $ is non-empty, but from here how will I conclude the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for a contradiction that $\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} F_k^\circ
$ is **not** dense in $\mathbb R.$ What that means is that there is an interval $I=[a,b]$ which is disjoint from $\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} F_k^\circ
.$ It follows that $F_k\cap I$ is a nowhere dense closed set. So $I$ is the union of countably many nowhere dense closed sets. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Since $I$ is complete , therefore it is not possible.

Comment: The same will aslo not holds for $\mathbb{R}^n$. In this case I will get $\prod_{j=1}^n [a_j,b_j]$ which is disjoint from $\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} F_k^\circ$